# Ubuntu: no space left on device while inodes and storage usage less than 10%

Tags: ubuntu, storage, inode

let me explain my specification of operating system i used and storage space information of my VPS

here is my operating system

```
vico@vicoartwork:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

My Inodes space

```
vico@vicoartwork:~$ df -i
Filesystem           Inodes IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/ploop27163p1 100195056 39685 100155371    1% /
devtmpfs              65536    55     65481    1% /dev
tmpfs                 65536     1     65535    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                 65536   161     65375    1% /run
tmpfs                 65536     2     65534    1% /run/lock
tmpfs                 65536    10     65526    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                  65536     1     65535    1% /run/shm
```

My storage space

```
vico@vicoartwork:~$ df -h
Filesystem         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/ploop27163p1   15G  1.3G   13G   9% /
devtmpfs           256M     0  256M   0% /dev
tmpfs              256M     0  256M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs              256M  4.4M  252M   2% /run
tmpfs              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs              256M     0  256M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none               256M     0  256M   0% /run/shm
```

this is my 3rd time rebuild VPS before this, i installed `GO` using `GVM` before. but it eats so much storage space. it around `450MB` because i compile go1.4 then go1.8.1. because eat so much space and `no space left on device` error occurred i rebuild my vps and download go binary from golang site.

when i trying to run go file it response like this

```
vico@vicoartwork:~/go1.8.1/go/InfusedProject/src/infused-japanese$ go run infused-japanese.go
# command-line-arguments
/home/vico/go1.8.1/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: flushing $WORK/command-line-arguments/_obj/exe/infused-japanese: write $WORK/command-line-arguments/_obj/exe/infused-japanese: no space left on device
```

often if dlv, which use same command

```
vico@vicoartwork:~/go1.8.1/go/InfusedProject/src/infused-japanese$ dlv debug --headless --listen=:2345 --api-version=2
mkdir /tmp/go-build722616582: no space left on device
exit status 1
```

commit 16kb file from my local computer, push to server. and pull

```
vico@vicoartwork:~/go1.8.1/go/InfusedProject/src/infused-japanese$ git pull origin master
Enter passphrase for key '/home/vico/.ssh/id_rsa':
remote: Counting objects: 4, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: unable to create temporary file: No space left on device
fatal: failed to write object
fatal: unpack-objects failed
```

i already try to search bulk unnecessary files, and delete it. but still not working.

so i tried to erase my go folder and download again

```
vico@vicoartwork:~$ rm -rf go1.8.1
vico@vicoartwork:~$ wget https://redirector.gvt1.com/edgedl/go/go1.8.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz
--2017-11-06 17:32:11--  https://redirector.gvt1.com/edgedl/go/go1.8.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz
Resolving redirector.gvt1.com (redirector.gvt1.com)... 74.125.130.138, 74.125.130.139, 74.125.130.100, ...
Connecting to redirector.gvt1.com (redirector.gvt1.com)|74.125.130.138|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://r3---sn-poqvn5u-jb36.gvt1.com/edgedl/go/go1.8.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz?cms_redirect=yes&expire=1510021931&ip=101.50.1.2&ipbits=0&mm=28&mn=sn-poqvn5u-jb36&ms=nvh&mt=1510007181&mv=u&pl=22&shardbypass=yes&sparams=expire,ip,ipbits,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,shardbypass&signature=31C9F99CCC6E64C815A0D1778B67BAF14251E059.48B5A4A4B42034F1958D81CD5FDBBBAFDEAA0E1C&key=cms1 [following]
--2017-11-06 17:32:11--  https://r3---sn-poqvn5u-jb36.gvt1.com/edgedl/go/go1.8.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz?cms_redirect=yes&expire=1510021931&ip=101.50.1.2&ipbits=0&mm=28&mn=sn-poqvn5u-jb36&ms=nvh&mt=1510007181&mv=u&pl=22&shardbypass=yes&sparams=expire,ip,ipbits,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,shardbypass&signature=31C9F99CCC6E64C815A0D1778B67BAF14251E059.48B5A4A4B42034F1958D81CD5FDBBBAFDEAA0E1C&key=cms1
Resolving r3---sn-poqvn5u-jb36.gvt1.com (r3---sn-poqvn5u-jb36.gvt1.com)... 114.4.7.14, 2407:0:0:13::e
Connecting to r3---sn-poqvn5u-jb36.gvt1.com (r3---sn-poqvn5u-jb36.gvt1.com)|114.4.7.14|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 91277742 (87M) [application/x-gzip]
go1.8.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz: No space left on device

Cannot write to 'go1.8.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz' (Success).
```

still error, it will only work again if i rebuild my vps.

Comment: For some reason, tmpfs isn't mounted on `/tmp`. What is `/tmp` on this machine? How much swap space do you have to back temporary files? (If tmpfs is being used.)

Comment: what filesystem is `/` ? Typing `df -h -T` gives this information. I'm curious to know if for example it could be btrfs

Comment: @DavidSchwartz i ever seen in one of article trying to remounting /tmp would help so i trying `umount: /tmp: not mounted` that's the response

Comment: @A.B here's the response `/dev/ploop27163p1 ext4       15G  779M   14G   6% /`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you control the host node, check to make sure the underlying filesystem backing the ploop image has space remaining and the image owner is under their disk quota. If you don't, you should contact your provider.

Comment: this owner of vps is irresponsible, they give me reference of my problem and i should solve by my own self. so i don't know either it's servers fault or my fault. so i make this case closed.